# How to set allowsEditing for UIImagePickerController only for videos selected from photo library in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm using UIImagePickerController in my applicaiton.
I'm showing the following alert in button action.

[image]

My code looks like the following in alertview delegate method:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if ([alertView.title isEqualToString:@"Choose"]) {
        if (buttonIndex == 1) { //Camera
            [self presentImagePickerControllerWithCamera:YES];
        }
        else if(buttonIndex == 2) { //Library
            [self presentImagePickerControllerWithCamera:NO];
        }
    }
}
```

and the content of the method 'presentImagePickerControllerWithCamera' is:

```
- (void)presentImagePickerControllerWithCamera:(BOOL)isCamera {

    CFStringRef mTypes[2] = { kUTTypeImage, kUTTypeMovie };
    CFArrayRef mTypesArray = CFArrayCreate(CFAllocatorGetDefault(), (const void**)mTypes, 2, &kCFTypeArrayCallBacks);
    imagePickerController.mediaTypes = (__bridge NSArray*)mTypesArray;
    imagePickerController.videoMaximumDuration = 60.0f;

    CFRelease(mTypesArray);
    if (isCamera) { // Showing the camera (Both Camera and video)
        imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        imagePickerController.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeMedium;
        imagePickerController.allowsEditing = NO;
    }
    else {  // Showing library (Both Pictures and videos)
        imagePickerController.allowsEditing = YES;
        imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
    }

    [self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Here i need to limit the video to 1 min when user is selecting video from library, so i wrote

```
imagePickerController.videoMaximumDuration = 60.0f;
```

and

```
    imagePickerController.allowsEditing = YES;
```

it's working fine. But When the user selects a picture from library i don't want editing(the square box on picture).
Is there any way to achieve it?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible with your current code.

You've assigned both the media types together. That will show you both image& video in to photo gallery. Once `UIImagePickerController` will show you'll not have access to it, I mean you can't know what user will select (an image or a video) before delegate get call.

So to achieve this with your case, you've to set each media type at once. And based on that media type, have to set `allowsEditing` property.